# How can I set a JavaScript variable from a form without a user clicking submit?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, variables, input

I have a form with several different text inputs. The value of each corresponds to a unique JavaScript variable. The variable is then written out on the page.

Is there a way to update the variable automatically so the user doesn't have to hit submit and reload the page each time? I have heard AJAX could be a potential answer to this, but I am unfamiliar with it. If that route is best, are there certain scripts that would be recommended?

Comment: You dont have to reinvent the wheel, try jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into jQuery as a good first start into javscript in the browser. For instance, you could write:

```
<form id="form-id">
    <input id="first" type="text" />
    <input id="second" type="text" />
    <input id="third" type="text" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var first, second, third;
$(function(){
    $("#form-id").submit(function(){
        first = $("#first").value();
        second = $("#second").value();
        third = $("#third").value();
        return false; //Prevent the form from submitting.
    });
});
</script>
```

http://jquery.com/

Comment: I was actually in the middle of doing the same type of post.  jQuery is probably what you are looking for, and you can use it to do AJAX calls in the background to your server for such features as autocomplete.